# Change between timezones

Tags: python, datetime

When I tried to utilize `datetime` module

```
In [31]: datetime.now()
Out[31]: datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 6, 8, 59, 35, 49991)
In [32]: str(datetime.now())
Out[32]: '2018-06-06 08:59:45.633486'
```

I intend to change to my local time but were lost in dozens of timezone modules and third-party package as pytz.

How could I change betweens timezones in a straight forward way?

Comment: This talk from DjangoCon 2018 is covering this topic and might git you some additional insight: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qabriMQ1SYs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in `datetime` module gives you the basic classes and data structures to deal with timezones, but it does not contain actual timezone data. That is because such data is occasionally updated and revised, and you wouldn't want that hardcoded into the Python distribution. That's where the `pytz` module comes in, which can be installed and kept up-to-date separately.

In practice you mostly deal with `datetime.datetime` and `pytz.timezone`:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo'))
```

If you're only working in UTC, that's the only timezone Python has built-in:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

You should carefully read the pytz usage notes when to use `datetime.astimezone`, `localize` and when to pass the timezone as argument to a `datetime` function: http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#example-usage.