# How to print out the timezone for a time object in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I am trying to print out a time with the timezone info as a string in the format `'%H:%M:%S%z'`. To do this, I am doing the following:

```
import pytz
import datetime

tz = pytz.timezone('Africa/Cairo')
time = datetime.datetime.strptime('14:24:41', '%H:%M:%S').time()
time = time.replace(tzinfo=tz)

print(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S%z'))
```

The result I get is simply `'14:24:41'`, even after replacing the tzinfo. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**
This question is not a duplicate, as the other one does not explain why the timezone is not being printed using the `strftime()` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change between timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716347/change-between-timezones)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) package, `%z` is

> UTC offset in the form ±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]] (empty string if the object is naive).

and

> For a naive object, the %z and %Z format codes are replaced by empty strings.
>   For an aware object:
>
> %z
>
> utcoffset() is transformed into a string of the form ±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]], where HH is a 2-digit string giving the number of UTC offset hours, MM is a 2-digit string giving the number of UTC offset minutes, SS is a 2-digit string giving the number of UTC offset seconds and ffffff is a 6-digit string giving the number of UTC offset microseconds.

Using your sample code, `time.utcoffset()` returns empty.

**Edit, with a fix**

You probably want to use the `.localize()` method, but to do so you would need to convert the string to a `datetime.datetime` and not the `datetime.time` object. This makes sense in a way: Wednesday at 0100 in Tokyo, is *Tuesday* 1700 in Berlin.

```
import pytz
import datetime

tz = pytz.timezone('Africa/Cairo')
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('14:24:41', '%H:%M:%S')
time = tz.localize(dt)

print(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S%z'))
```

Comment: That is interesting. How do you actually set the timezone for a time object then? Because, clearly using `time.replace(tzinfo=tz)` did not work.

Comment: I edited to add a fix to your sample. If you really need to work with a `datetime.time` object, you should call `.time()` after adding the TZ offset.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed the problem.